# Not allowed to add .txt file to Computer

Tags: command-line

For a homework assignment I have to execute some commands and report the results.

But when I try `du /var > tmp.txt` it says I am not allowed to access `tmp.txt`.

I have tried to use a different name for the file but no different results, I have tried to add the text file to the Computer folder in the GUI but I am unable to do that too.

I am in the `sudo` group, `sudo echo ok` returns `ok`

My question: why can't I add a simple `txt` file to the Computer folder and how can I do this?

Comment: @snoop the error is in Dutch, but translate its simply " Bash: tmp.txt: Access denied"

Comment: Yeah, then its a access issue on that particular path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect output, the `sudo` is not applied to the output file.

You can do it by

```
du /var | sudo tee tmp.txt
```

or

```
sudo -i
du /var > tmp.txt
exit
```

Comment: @terdon Why was `sudo su` changed to `-i`?  this allowed me to log in as root (i think) and write the txt file where i wanted to originally

Comment: @Vahx both `sudo -i` and `sudo su` do essentially the same thing. There is just rarely, if ever, any good reason to run `sudo su` since that's running two processes and is just a more complex way of doing `sudo -i`. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222) for more.

Comment: I agree that `sudo -i` is a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

You may be in a folder where your user doesn't have permissions.

Try `du /var > ~/tmp.txt` to write the file to your home directory, you should have write permission there.

Comment: This works, thank you. it seems that being in the sudo group is not enough to have full authorization of everything. Not sure if i can work around that or how to log in as root as default.

Comment: Is is strongly discouraged to log in as _root_ as default! Use sudo to execute commands as root.

Comment: I understand the security reasons, but this is all on a virtual machine, which i only use for school purposes  atm.